# ADO .NET OUT Variables Oracle 10G vs 11G

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle11g, ado.net

Issue:
OUT variables from the procedures are not being returned.

Background:
I recently updated an application from Oracle 10g to Oracle 11G. WE are using an 12c version of Oracle client.

The application runs on .NET 3.5.

```
Database db = CreateDatabase(connectionName);
            var dbCmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand(procedureName);

            ConvertParams(ref dbCmd, parameters);

            try
            {
                iReturn = db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCmd, _transaction);
                if (transaction == null) //if a transaction hasn't been passed, it isn't intended to has control over commit/rollback out of method, so app can do it
                    _transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (transaction == null)
                    _transaction.Rollback();
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                DebugSpCommand(procedureName, parameters);
                GetOutputParams(ref parameters, dbCmd);
                if (transaction == null)
                {
                    if (_transaction.Connection != null)
                        _transaction.Connection.Close();
                    _transaction.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        {
            Framework.ErrorHandling.ErrorHandler.HandleException(ex, "DATA_LAYER_POLICY");
            Framework.Logging.Logger.Write(ex.Message, LogCategories.Debug);
            iReturn = ex.Code;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Framework.ErrorHandling.ErrorHandler.HandleException(ex, "DATA_LAYER_POLICY");
            Framework.Logging.Logger.Write(ex.Message, LogCategories.Debug);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use out variable in Stored procedure

Comment: The problem was that my out variable in the PL/SQL procedure was returning an number and my C# code was expecting an char.
For some reason it was working on Oracle 10G.